# MSSQL: How to get statistics of reading of table?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to get the amount of 'selects' from a mssql table?

I mean without rewriting application to log every request or without parsing sql profile logs...

Is there any build-in tool (sql request)?

Comment: You can CREATE SERVER AUDIT to do this, but there's nothing enabled by default to my knowledge to track all SELECT statements.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server maintains index usage statistics since last restart. You can use *user_reads* column from query bellow to get wanted statistics:

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(ddius.[object_id], ddius.database_id) AS [object_name] ,
        ddius.index_id ,
        ddius.user_seeks ,
        ddius.user_scans ,
        ddius.user_lookups ,
        ddius.user_seeks + ddius.user_scans + ddius.user_lookups 
                                                     AS user_reads ,
        ddius.user_updates AS user_writes ,
        ddius.last_user_scan ,
        ddius.last_user_update
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ddius
WHERE   ddius.database_id > 4 -- filter out system tables
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(ddius.OBJECT_ID, 'IsUserTable') = 1
        AND ddius.index_id > 0  -- filter out heaps 
        AND database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY user_reads  DESC
```